# Shape Key 10 is not working well

Tags: modeling, shape-keys

Well, I was doing the model's facial expressions with the shape keys but suddenly adding the number 10 happened this to me. All others are fine, but after the 10, happens this and I do not know what to do...

[image]

Download file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/bzts92ted9w5mx7/AAA.blend

Comment: Please add more information. We have no way to know how you set up your scene with the images provided. Please make a detailed description on how you created your shape keys.   Making the file available would be the easiest way to find out.

Comment: @cegaton okay I added a download file